# jQuery find next anchor element inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><a href="hello">Hello</a><div class="yo"></div></td>
    <td><a href="bye">Bye</a><div class="yo"></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a href="foo">Foo</a><div class="yo"></div></td>
    <td><a href="bar">Bar</a><div class="yo"></div></td>
</tr>
...
<!-- Rows continue on... -->
```

The divs have a listener for tab keydown, so whenever a tab is pressed it should go to the next link. (or perhaps it's enough to go to the next td element?)

For instance I click on `Hello` anchor, then `Bye` anchor should get focused. If I click on `Bye` anchor then `Foo` anchor should get focused.

Comment: you have jquery functions like `.next()` and `.focus()`

Comment: @PedroEstrada, `.next()` works with siblings, but the anchors are not siblings of each other.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Add a class to all the anchor tags you want included in this focusing-chain for a less confusing selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the index of the clicked link and call `.focus()` on the next element in the array:

```
var $links = $('table a');
$links.on('click', function() {
    $links.eq($links.index(this)+1).focus();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qcbozbyn/1/

Comment: I already have a listener attached for each link, how can I inside that listener get the next anchor element and focus it?

Comment: Pretty much exactly the same way, you just need to have the collection of all links `var $links = $('table a');`  so you can get the index of the clicked element and execute `$links.eq($links.index(this)+1).focus();` inside your current click handler

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to jquery and js, what does "this" mean in this context?

Comment: @PeterWarbo `this` in this particular context refers to the current DOM node (the event target), `jQueryCollection.index(DOMNode)` will return the numeric index of the passed element, +1 gives us the next element in the list. `jQueryCollection.eq(N)` returns the Nth child of the collection. So we are saying: look up the event target node (clicked `<a>` tag) in the list of all `<a>` tags in our table, add 1 to that to get the next `<a>` tag and call `.focus()` on that. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Ah, thanks! That clears things up. Actually I noticed a typo in my code now, my td's look like this `<td><a href="foo">Foo</a><div class="foo"></div></td>` and I have a listener on the div... from the listener on the div how can I get the index of the anchor element inside the same td?

Comment: Pretty much the same setup, you would use `$(this).prev()` instead of `this` in the call to `.index` e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/qcbozbyn/2/

Answer (score 0):

How about working with jquery Next() and prev() methods

```
$("table tr td a").click(function(){
   var me = $(this) ;
    var nextElm = me.closest("td").next();
    if(nextElm.length>0){
        nextElm.find("a").css("color","green");
    }
    else{
        var prevElm = me.closest("td").prev();
        if(prevElm.length>0){
            prevElm.find("a").css("color","red");
        }
    }
});
```

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/7fw2oeLm/